# Simplifying Linear combination

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

It's been a while since I've used the Euclidean algorithm and I'm having some trouble simplifying this equation (480-68*7)-(7-1*(480-68*7))=1 to be the form of the linear combination 7x + 480y = 1

All help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Would it help to think of it as $(b-68a)-(a-(b-68a))$?

Comment: This is $2(480-68\cdot 7)-7=2\cdot 480-137\cdot 7$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, that does help make it more clear but I'm still a little stuck on grouping the terms.

Comment: $(b-68a)-(a-(b-68a)) = (b-68a)-(a+68a-b) = b-68a-(69a-b)=b-68a-69a+b=\dots$